# Nest thermostat E74 error - no power to Rh Wire

Tags: nest

It was working with no issues for last 3 years. Today it suddenly showing this error. Any help appreciated.

Comment: What make and model is your air-handler/furnace? If you take the Nest off and jumper Rh to W, does the heat turn on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Bit of Nest history***

Nest often has a sub base issue. Usually the issue is contained to the cooling side. Rh is power input for the heating side. So that wouldn't be my first guess.

***Test***

Remove Rh and G and connect them together with a wire nut or simply twisting together. It doesn't have to be a very good connection, it just has to be a connection. This will bring your fan on. Now what you will want to do is, move to a location where you can hear the fan running. If it is running that confirms power. If it's not running you will need to identify the issue it may be a breaker, the furnace switch is off, the fuse in the furnace is blown, or one of many other power related issues.

***If it's running***

If the fan is running you can remove the RH wire from the G terminal and connected to the W wire. Now after a few minutes you should have heat blowing through your vents. If you do have heat blowing through your vents then I would suggest calling nest and getting them to replace your sub base they usually do it for free.

***Conclusion***

If you're unable to resolve the problem due to it being a power issue then that is another question which I am happy to help with but for now try the method outlined above and let us know how it worked.

Comment: Thanks for the troubleshooting tips. The problem was faulty Nest thermostat.

Answer (score 1):

I called a technician and he found out the cause is faulty Nest thermostat. I was using Nest 3rd gen thermostat. He removed the Nest and installed my old Honeywell non-wifi thermostat and my air conditioning started working again. It's sad that $250 Nest stopped working in 3 years. Mostly I won't go back to Nest again, I'll use Honeywell.

Answer (score 1):

If gen 3. Disconnect your common wire and do not use. Thermostat should reset to 4 wire system and work

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Note that the OP posted that Nest tech support told him the unit was defective. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Answer (score 1):

You could also have a safety switch that is connected to the condensation line. This sensor detects water that has backed up in the line and causes the power to shut off to prevent water damage and over flow. Just pull the safety switch cap off to see if there is water present. Depend on how blocked it is and the time from when the unit shuts off and when you check the line, the water might have drained down a bit to allow the unit to run again for a few minutes .

You'll need to blow out the debris in the line.